# I can't invoke a constructor inside another constructor in a JPQL query. What's an efficient workaround?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

It seems I can't invoke a constructor inside another constructor in a JPQL query, like this

```java
TypedQuery<QuestionCommentResponseDto> = entityManager.createQuery("""
            SELECT new QuestionCommentResponseDto (
            qc.id, q.id, qc.createdDate, qc.modifiedDate, qc.text, new AccountResponseDto(
                a.id, a.username
                )
            ) FROM QuestionComment qc JOIN FETCH Question q JOIN FETCH Account a
            WHERE qc.id = :id
        """, QuestionCommentResponseDto.class)
```

**How am I supposed to achieve the same effect then in the most efficient way possible?** Subqueries like `qc.text, (SELECT new AccountResponseDto(a.id, a.username)` don't work too (the part after `qc.text` is problematic). The IDE says

> '(', , FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '('
> Should I simply query for one DTO and then for another?

A bit of context

```java
    @Override
    public Optional<QuestionCommentResponseDto> getByQuestionCommentId(Long questionCommentId) {
    // the query goes here
```

```java
// I can make it a regular class if it's necessary
public record QuestionCommentResponseDto(Long id, Long questionId, LocalDateTime createdDate,
                                         LocalDateTime modifiedDate, String text, AccountResponseDto owner) {}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "question_comments")
public class QuestionComment {

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @NotNull
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @NotNull
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime modifiedDate;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Account owner; // includes the fields id and username

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Question question; // includes the id field
```

If I omitted some important parts of code, please let me know (it seems to me, no code is needed at all in this case since it's not a debugging question)

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a SQL View or even Materialized View in your DB?
Then you can have an entity (over your view) to support JPA Interface-based Projections.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces

With Spring Data you can query Materialized View same way as a table.
And I would respect separation of concerns and create a @Component
to map an Entity to desired business object (Dto).